# Can I Render a Point List Primitive

Tags: sharpdx

Does SharpDX support rendering a list of point primitives ? I cannot see any overloads on the GraphicsContext.Draw commands, so they all seem to expect a triangle list.

I am using SharpDX.DirectX11.

Comment: SharpDX comes with several DirectX graphics API. Which API are you referring?

Answer (score 1):

Direct3D11 supports [Point List primitives](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205124%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). See [Direct3D11.Device.DeviceContext.InputAssembler.PrimitiveTopology](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476455%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property and enum [PrimitiveTopology](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476189%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)